# SlimPHP + MySQL or how to get nested JSON froim relaite db tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, slim

I have two tables:

**Projects**

- ID
- name
- desc
- userID (foreign key)

**Users**

- ID
- email
- role
- firstName
- lastName

Now i use SlimPHP + MySQL and have this code:

```
function projects() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects";
    try {
      $db = getConnection();
      $query = $db->query($sql);
      $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      $db = null;
      return $result;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      return array("error" => $e->getMessage());
    }
}

function users() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    try {
      $db = getConnection();
      $query = $db->query($sql);
      $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      $db = null;
      return $result;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      return array("error" => $e->getMessage());
    }
}

function user($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = $id";
    try {
      $db = getConnection();
      $query = $db->query($sql);
      $result = $query->fetchObject();
      $db = null;
      return $result;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      return array("error" => $e->getMessage());
    }
}

$app->get('/projects/', function() use ($app) {
    $projects = projects();
    $stack = array();

    foreach($projects as $project) {
      $project->userID = user($project->userID);
      array_push($stack, $project);
    }
    echo json_encode($stack);
});
```

Code fetch data from **projects** with corresponding user from **users** table, something like this in JSON:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "name": "DORE",
    "description": "Aliquam euismod",
    "userID": {
        "ID": "1",
        "email": "someperson@example.com",
        "firstName": "Alexander",
        "lastName": "Belko",
        "role": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "name": "STPL",
    "description": "Aliquam euismod",
    "userID": {
        "ID": "1",
        "email": "someperson@example.com",
        "firstName": "Alexander",
        "lastName": "Belko",
        "role": "1"
    }
  }
]
```

But I think that I do something wrong. Maybe someone can suggest more beautiful practice?

Comment: Maybe do a mySql query for projects with JOIN on users? What does your db structure look like?

Comment: My DB schema: http://clip2net.com/s/7hXN0s

Comment: So each project has 1 or more users?

Comment: One or more than one.

Comment: How do you store more than 1 userID in projects? There is only 1 field? Comma separated list? Wouldn't it be better to look for the users and find out in which projects they are involved?

Comment: Later I will do projects_users table(projectID, userID). But now I more interested in PHP implementation